# Safe area insets wrong after changing window rootViewController

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I am using `inputAccessoryView` of `UIViewController`. Everything works fine until I change `UIWindow`s `rootViewController`. After that `safeAreaInsets` for portrait are reported as landscape and other way around.

This is only happening when changing from `rootViewController` that has keyboard input.

Here is example project that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/jcavar/ChangeRootSafeArea

I guess it is some magic in `UITextEffectsWindow`that causes this. I tried removing it completely before changing `rootViewController`but then input accessory view doesn't come up anymore.

Any ideas about this?

Comment: It might not be related to the issue you have mentioned.
but, you are using `super.viewDidLoad()` in `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`

Comment: I managed to workaround this problem by setting `UITextEffectsWindow` `rootViewController` to `nil` and then back to original root